In spark physical planning, what kind of optimization is happening?
I have a quote from a blog on the physical planning in spark. I want to understand what it means
Quote

Suppose, there’s a join query between two tables. In that join operation, one of them is a large table and the other one is a small table with a different number of partitions scattered in different nodes across the cluster (it can be in a single rack or a different rack). Spark decides which partitions should be joined at the start (order of joining), the type of join, etc. for better optimization.

My understanding of the join in spark (non broadcast) is the following

Repartition both the dataframes according to the join keys (hashing hence the same keys from both the dfs end up on the same executor). Also, the repartitions should be sorted
Merge them using two finger algorithm (not sure if this is the term but it is pretty intuitive to merge two sorted arrays)

The quoted text above has a line Spark decides which partitions should be joined at the start (order of joining). How does the order of joining on partitions result in optimization for the merge strategy that spark follows? What does the order of joining even mean for a spark join?

without additional explanation from the author, the sentence seems to be wrong - there's no sense in "decides which partitions should be joined", when these partitions are actually raw table data
